# UWP CommunityToolkit Messenger async handler

Tags: c#, async-await, uwp, windows-community-toolkit, community-toolkit-mvvm

I have a UWP [project](https://github.com/BSVN/linphone-windows10/tree/feature/2-add-call-back) and I want to message passing between `ViewModel` and `View` with [CommunityToolkit MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

As you can see in my `ViewModel` we have something like below

```cs
        private async void CallbackClick()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                CallbackDto callback = callbackQueue.Pop();
                if (callback is null)
                    break;

                callbackQueue.Push(new CallbackDto(callback.Number, DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.ToUnixTimeSeconds()));
                string normalizedAddress = callback.Number;
                BSN.LinphoneSDK.Call outgoingCall = await LinphoneManager.Instance.NewOutgoingCall($"{normalizedAddress}");
                await outgoingCall.WhenEnded();
                // TODO: It is mandatory for backing to Dialer from InCall, but it is very bugous and must fix it
                await Task.Delay(1000);
                Task<CancellationToken> cancellationTokenTask = WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send<ContinueCallbackAnsweringRequestMessage>();
                CancellationToken cancellationToken = await cancellationTokenTask;
                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                    break;
            }
        }
```

And I have register on message in `Dialer.xaml.cs` in `NavigatedTo` like below

```cs
 WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ContinueCallbackAnsweringRequestMessage>(this, async (r, message) =>
            {
                var continueCallbackAnsweringDialog = new MessageDialog("آیا مایل به ادامه پاسخ‌دهی به تماس‌های درخواستی هستید؟");
                TaskCompletionSource<CancellationToken> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<CancellationToken>(TaskCreationOptions.RunContinuationsAsynchronously);
                continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
                    "بلی",
                    new UICommandInvokedHandler((IUICommand command) =>
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(new CancellationToken(false));
                    })));
                continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand(
                    "خیر",
                    new UICommandInvokedHandler((IUICommand command) =>
                    {
                        tcs.SetResult(new CancellationToken(true));
                    })));
                continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.DefaultCommandIndex = 0;
                continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.CancelCommandIndex = 1;
                await continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.ShowAsync();

                message.Reply(tcs.Task);
            });
```

In this scenario I got a `InvalidOperationException` on `WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send`. **My question is how to handle this situation?**

In another side, if I remove `async` and `await` keyword in handler, my code is work correctly. but the problem is I do not await on `IAsyncOperation` and I want to `await` on in it.

I add [discussion on CommunityToolkit GitHub](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/discussions/331#discussion-4187337) about that.

Comment: No, my `ContinueCallbackAnsweringRequestMessage` is inherit from `RequestMessage` and I need for response of sending message to continue working

Comment: Then pass the non-awaited task returned by `continueCallbackAnsweringDialog.ShowAsync` directly to `message.Reply`.

Comment: It is not my desirable, because I want to return another value, as you can see and in general we want to run many async command in handler and I want to learn how to call multiple `await` in handler without any problem?

Comment: The `MessageHandler` will return as soon as you await something so this won't work.

Comment: But I need make many await command on it, How to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how to handle this situation?

Since the `MessageHandler` won't (can't) be awaited by the toolkit, it returns when you call `await ...`.

You could try something like this:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ContinueCallbackAnsweringRequestMessage>(
    this, (r, m) => m.Reply(ShowDialogAndWaitForResult()));
```

...where `ShowDialogAndWaitForResult()` is a custom `async` method that returns a `Task<T>`, calls the `ShowAsync()` of the dialog and wait for  the result.

Another option is implement your own blocking (non-async) dialog. Or consider another solution which don't involve a messenger.

Comment: How to make `IAsyncOperation` synchronous?

Comment: Try to pass a custom `async` method that shows the dialog to the `Reply` method. See my edit.

Comment: I think maybe you correct as you can see in https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/332#issue-1291426232 , I test it and say to you :)